# Filter columns in a csv file and output plot

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to filter a column in a CSV just like you would in excel. Then based on that filter I would like to have it call a different column and output the data from that column into a plot.

I have tried to print the code on its own and its prints correctly. I am just not sure about the syntax. When I print the code it shows that I can correctly search through a column

```
data.head()
print('banana',
      data[('Sub-Dept')] == 'Stow Each') #and data[('Sub-Dept')] == 'Stow Each Nike', 'Each Stow to Prime', 'Each Stow to Prime E', 'Each Stow to Prime W', 'Stow to Prime LeadPA')
```

But I do not know how to get it to filter that first, then plot underneath there. I am fairly new to this.

I have a column has many different filterable names inside of it. I want to call those names above.

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns 

x = []
y = []

data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\rmond\Downloads\PS_csvFile.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1", skiprows=6)


new_data = data.loc[(data['Sub-Dept'] == 'Stow Each')]
sns.set(style="whitegrid") #this is strictly cosmetic, you can change it any time
ax = sns.countplot(x='U.S. OSHA Recordable?', data=new_data)
plt.bar(x, y, label='Loaded from file!')
plt.ylabel('Quantity of Injuries')
plt.title('Injuries (past 4 weeks)')
plt.show()
```

Right now, I am expecting it to out put 1 graph that has 2 bars. Problem: it shows a quantity of 80 on 1 bar and 20 on another bar. Solution: After the data is filtered from another column it should show 21 in 1 bar and 7 in another bar inside the same graph.

The graphing portion works great and so does pulling the data from the excel. The only part I do not know how to do is filtering that column and then graphing based on that filter. I am not sure what the code should look like and where it should go. please help

CSV FILE HERE: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yJ6iQL-bOvGSLAKPcPXqgk9aKLqUEmPK

Comment: please show an example  of your dataframe and also your dataframe filtered

Comment: Can you please show an example of your dataframe or share the .csv file with us?

Comment: you just need to filter using `.loc` try `new_data = data.loc[data['Sub-Dept'] == 'Stow Each']` then plot it out using seaborn.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I saved the file to my drive. I was not sure how else to share it with you guys. I will start working on the .loc like Datanovice mentioned. I am not sure where to place that code though. That is kinda my problem. But I will try and figure it out

Comment: YES! it worked, thanks Datanovice. I am able to filter the column by 1 item as you mentioned. But I need to filter that column by 6 items at once. So how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am so happy to have figured this out. I had trouble finding the answer to this on the internet. So I hope this helps someone else in the future. Thanks to Datanovice for the initial idea into .loc. That helped me get to the next steps.The rest of my answer came from here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-extracting-rows-using-loc/

Sorry I left my comments in the code

```
import pandas as pd # powerful data visualization library
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # allows us to plot things
import csv # allows us to import and use CSV commands which are simple but effective
import seaborn as sns #https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html
# This website saved my life https://www.pythonforengineers.com/introduction-to-pandas/
# use this to check the available styles: plt.style.available

x = []
y = []

data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\rmond\Downloads\PS_csvFile.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1", skiprows=6, index_col="Sub-Dept") #skiprows allows you to skip the comments on top... & ecoding allows pandas to work on this CSV
new_data = data.loc[["Each Stow to Prime", "Each Stow to Prime E", "Each Stow to Prime W", "Stow Each", "Stow Each Nike", "Stow to Prime LeadPA",]]
sns.set(style="whitegrid") #this is strictly cosmetic, you can change it any time
ax = sns.countplot(x='U.S. OSHA Recordable?', data=new_data) #magic, so seaborn is designed to pull the dats from a URL. But when using pandas and seaborn there is a work around
# the key is that "countplot" literally does the work for you. its awesome
plt.bar(x, y, label='Loaded from file!')
plt.ylabel('Quantity of Injuries')
plt.title('Stow Injuries (past 4 weeks)')
plt.show() # shows the plot to the user
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Try pandas.query()

Pandas [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) might be useful.

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\rmond\Downloads\PS_csvFile.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1", skiprows=6)

new_data = data.query("Sub-Dept == Stow Each or
                       Sub-Dept == RF_Pick")
```